# ArangoDb Web Graph visualization - Select node attributes

Tags: arangodb

I'm using ArangoDb Graph web interface.
I have created a graph with nodes from different collections.
As each node collection has its own attribute set, is there any way to choose different labels to be shown?

[image: Graph Interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there currently is no way to select the label attribute per vertex collection.

You may want to open a feature request via github, or take a look at https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/js/apps/system/_admin/aardvark/APP/frontend/js/views/graphViewer.js#L693 - However, the used Sigma.js library has to support it in first place.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem before. But, after setting the start node, the labels appear correctly.
[image: ArangoDB with Portugues words]

Otherwise, the arrows, as you can see in the picture, do not appear. I set documents and edges. I tried changing colors, types, label, and nothing.
[image: Edge settings]

The worst problem is that I can save the properties one thousand times and, if I close the graph open it again, it loses the changes. I tried to find a Python code to set the label, but nothing till now.

Maybe the number of edges (1,435,022)?

Comment: I had the same errors in 2020. That was the reason to try other graph databases. I do not understand the reason for not fixing that.